# Expanding string to specific length

Tags: pascal

How do I expand string of text?
I need to turn e. g. `string` which is `'abcde'` into `newstring`, `'abcdeabcdeabcd'`, so `length(newstring)` is equal to `length(someotherstring)`. Main purpose - generating keys for the Vigenere's encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The following function expands a string by repeating its characters:

```
function RepeatString(const AText: string; ANewLength: Integer): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  if ANewLength <= Length(AText) then
  begin
    Result := Copy(AText, 1, ANewLength);
    Exit;
  end;

  SetLength(Result, ANewLength);
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
    Result[i] := AText[(i - 1) mod Length(AText) + 1];

end;
```

If you are using a modern Delphi version of Pascal, this can be written more neatly:

```
function RepeatString(const AText: string; ANewLength: Integer): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  if ANewLength <= AText.Length then
    Exit(Copy(AText, 1, ANewLength));

  SetLength(Result, ANewLength);
  for i := 1 to Result.Length do
    Result[i] := AText[(i - 1) mod AText.Length + 1];

end;
```

## There is a "but"

**However**, in your case (implementing the Vigenère cipher), it is a bad idea to use such a function. You don't need it, so you will only waste memory (and CPU usage) creating this extended version of the string.

Instead, use the original string. Instead of using chars 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... of an extended version of the string, use chars 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, ... of the original string.

Something like this (haven't tested fully):

```
function Vigenere(const AText, AKey: string): string;
var
  KeyChrs: array of Byte;
  n, i: Integer;
begin

  n := Length(AKey);
  if n = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Vigenère key is empty.');

  SetLength(KeyChrs, n);
  for i := 1 to n do
    if InRange(Ord(AKey[i]), Ord('A'), Ord('Z')) then
      KeyChrs[i - 1] := Ord(AKey[i]) - Ord('A')
    else
      raise Exception.Create('Invalid character in Vigenère key. Only upper-case English letters allowed.');

  SetLength(Result, Length(AText));
  for i := 1 to Length(AText) do
    if InRange(Ord(AText[i]), Ord('A'), Ord('Z')) then
      Result[i] := Chr(Ord('A') + (Ord(AText[i]) - Ord('A') + KeyChrs[(i - 1) mod n]) mod 26)
    else if InRange(Ord(AText[i]), Ord('a'), Ord('z')) then
      Result[i] := Chr(Ord('a') + (Ord(AText[i]) - Ord('a') + KeyChrs[(i - 1) mod n]) mod 26)
    else
      Result[i] := AText[i];

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lazarus or Free Pascal, use [strutils.dupestring](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/dupestring.html) like this:

```
   newstr:=dupestring(oldstr,4);  // concatenates oldstr 4 times into dupestring
   // If you need to remove n chars from the last pattern (in your example n=1), use
   setlength(newstr,length(newstr)-n);
```